# How to turn off Alt+f1 shortcut

Tags: 16.04, shortcut-keys, launcher

I am using Intellij and used to use Alt+F1 to navigate between different views. I have begun to use Intelij in Ubuntu but when I press Alt+F1 the first icon on the launcher will be activated. I could not find this keyboard shortcut under Ubuntu shortcuts. I wonder if it is possible to change this shortcut key for focus on launcher.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find this setting in CompizConfig Settings Manager (CCSM): **Desktop** section → **Ubuntu Unity Plugin** → **Launcher** tab → "Key to put keyboard-focus on launcher"

You can install CCSM from the Software Center, or run

```
sudo apt install compizconfig-settings-manager
```

And you might need to log out and back in for it to take effect.

Source and more details: [How to Tweak Unity on Ubuntu With the CompizConfig Settings Manager - How to Geek](https://www.howtogeek.com/101006/how-to-tweak-unity-on-ubuntu-with-the-compizconfig-settings-manager/)

Comment: Thanks for answer. I edited Behaviour tab to Launcher tab. Because in the version of CompizConfig that I installed I found setting under Launcher and there was no Behaviour